# Why do my dynamically generated forms not update correctly when I delete one of them using Vue?

Tags: forms, input, vuejs2, v-for, rerender

I want to populate a form with multiple text input fields. However, when I delete one of these input fields, the UI doesn't update correctly according to the data present.

**Condition.vue**

```
        <template v-slot:custom-form>
            <el-row v-for="(condition, index) of customFormData" type="flex" :key="`${randomSalt}${index}`" class="condition row-bg" :justify="isElse(condition) ? 'start' : 'space-around'">
                <el-col class="operator" :class="[ index === 0 ? 'operator-if' : '', isElse(condition) ? 'operator-else' : '']" :span=".5">
                {{condition.type.toLowerCase() === 'else' ? 'ELSE' : index > 0 ? 'ELSE IF' : 'IF'}}
                </el-col>
                <el-col ref="index" v-if="condition.type.toLowerCase() !== 'else'" :span="6">
                    <editable-value name="inputAction" dataType="property" v-model="condition.inputAction" :schema="condition.schema"></editable-value>
                </el-col>
                <el-col v-if="condition.type.toLowerCase() !== 'else'" class="operator" :span=".5">
                    =
                </el-col>
                <el-col v-if="condition.type.toLowerCase() !== 'else'" :span="6">
                    <editable-value name="inputActionValue" dataType="value" v-model="condition.inputActionValue" :schema="condition.schema"></editable-value>
                </el-col>
                <el-col v-if="condition.type.toLowerCase() !== 'else'" class="operator" :span=".5">
                    THEN
                </el-col>
                <el-col :span="6">
                    <editable-value name="ouputAction" dataType="output" v-model="condition.ouputAction" :schema="condition.schema"></editable-value>
                </el-col>
                <el-col :span=".5">
                    <el-button icon="el-icon-delete" type="text" plain class="trans scale delete-condition el-col-offset-1 ev-controls" @click="e => { deleteCondition(index) }"></el-button>
                </el-col>
            </el-row>
        </template>
export default {
    components: { EditableValue },
    data () {
        return {
            customFormData: [
                {
                    type: 'if',
                    schema: Schema
                }
            ],
            salt: 1043423
        }
    },
    computed: {
        randomSalt () {
            return this.salt + this.getRnd()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        deleteCondition (index) {
            this.customFormData.splice(index, 1)
        },
        getRnd () {
            return Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000 / (Math.random() - 1)) + 1)
        },
        chainCondition (type) {
            this.customFormData.push({ ...this.customFormData[this.customFormData.length], type, schema: this.schema })
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, each **Editable-Values** component represents an input field, `customFormData` is an array listing each row of input fields belonging to the main form. When deleting a row, we simply splice that row from the array and vice versa for addition.

**Main Problem**

Everything else works fine except when I delete a row that is neither the first nor last in the array. When such a deletion happens, the data **(code)** in the app is correct and represents the deletion.

The **UI** however, seems as if the row below the intended one was deleted. Using pseudocode, the behavior is as follows:

```
UI
<row 1 data="one"/>
<row 2 data="two" />
<row 3 data="three"/>

Code
data: {
 1: 'one',
 2: 'two',
 3: 'three'
}

// If we delete row 2, the UI becomes as follows:
UI
<row 1 data="one"/>
<row 2 data="two" />

Code
data: {
 1: 'one',
 3: 'three'
}
```

What can I do to make sure that each row represents its data correctly.?

**I tried forcing a rerender** by changing the row key, however, this just ends up displaying empty input fields. I have also tried using an object instead of an array to display the rows, but the results are much worse, data doesn't seem so reactive with objects.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem most probably comes from using v-for `index` as a [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key). `key` must be unique and stable - `index` satisfies only 1st condition (when the 2nd row is deleted, 3rd row now gets index 2 instead of 3 and Vue rendering mechanism makes false assumptions about what needs to be re-rendered/updated in the DOM)

Workaround with random `key` doesn't work either. `computed` caches the value and changes only when some of the **reactive dependencies** are changed (`this.salt` in this case) so you are actually using same `key` for all the rows. Changing it into method will lead to actually re-rendering everything all the time - this is not something you want either

Only way to solve it correctly is to assign unique ID to each row - it may very well be an index but it must be stored with each row so it does not change every time some row is deleted...

Comment: This definitely solved my problem. All I did was generate a random key for each of the rows in ```customFormData```, stored it as a unique ```id``` for each row, like ```{type: 'if', id: uniqueRandomValue}```, and then I used this id as the row ```key```. Worked like a charm, thanks.